# Flutter web shortcuts between widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter web app that is Outlook style. A user can create a message and click a send button.

I want to add the ability to send using a keyboard combination like Alt+S.

I am trying to do this using the shortcuts widget with intents and actions.

The problem I am facing is that the widget where the message is composed and the widget where the send button is are sibling widgets. They have a common parent widget.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Yaron

I can get it two work if I tab to widget where the send button is but don't understand where to place the shortcuts and action widgets if I want to get it to work between two sibling widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by wrapping the parent widget with CallbackShortcuts widgets and a focus widget:
return CallbackShortcuts(
bindings: {
LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.alt, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyS): () {
print(
"sending request number ${widget.genreRequest.requestIdentifier}");
_handleRequestSubmit(widget.genreRequest.requestIdentifier, 1);
},
},
child: Focus(
autofocus: true,
child: ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be surpassed if you write your send functionality   in a separate function. You can them use it in both the intent and the button.